# Unexpected error when joining computer to AC/DC Samba 4

Tags: samba, kerberos, domain

I present the problem:
On a PC with 32-bit Debian Jessie, using Samba 4.1.7 I have a Domain Controller, it has been running for 2 years but since 2 weeks ago it is giving me the following error:
When I try to include a PC with Window7 or Windows8 (I have not tried XP or Win10) new to the domain it gives me the following error:

[image: Error trying to join the domain. Only this operation is allowed on the main domain controller.]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlHHK.jpg)

Traduction:

> Error trying to join the domain.
> Only this operation is allowed on the main domain controller.

I already check the logs and there is nothing out of the ordinary.

I already try with the samba tool:

```
samba-tool dbcheck
```

And I did not find any error in database.

Can someone help me or tell me where there is information about this error? Or help me with kerberos documentation?

Comment: Do you have a second (or backup) domain controller?

Comment: Nop, I just "inherit" the services.

Comment: I just realize, when I try:
kinit admin@domain.name

The answer is:
"kinit: KDC reply did not match expectatios while getting initial credentials"

Comment: That should be `kinit admin@DOMAIN.NAME` (capital letters)

Comment: What do you mean that you "inherit" the services? Does whoever manages the domain controller have a second one? (This error is typical if the nominated DC is no longer the primary.)

Comment: When I try to log in with the "kinit admin@DOMAIN.NAME", I should not return something similar to:
"Password for administrator@DOMAIN.NAME:
Warning: Your password will expire in 41 days on Wed Jul 16 13:55:20 2014 "

It does not!

Inherit: the previous system administrator left the job and it was my turn to take over the job, I am a recent graduate, I have little experience and I have never encountered a problem like this.
Sorry for my english.